# How to make <p> switch to a new line inside a DIV, when it the text exceeds the width, when using float left

Tags: html, css

I have two divs and a wrapper div around them.

The wrapper div is 950px in width. The first DIV inside the wrapper is 450px in width.

The last div is supposed to adjust itself according to the space left. Which is 500px.

When i wirte a paragraph in the last DIV, and the text exceeds the width of the div, it will put the div on a new line, instead of putting the text on a new line. The div will stretch to 950px.

I am using `float: left;`

How can i fix this, so that the paragraph makes a new line inside the last DIV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are floating both inner divs, you can remove the float from the second one; that will solve your problem: text in the second div will be displayed to the right of the first one, even if the text is longer than one line.

Otherwise, we may need more info, like what other styles do you have, what browser do you have the problem in, etc.

Comment: This seems more like it. Is there a way to push the second div downwards, when it exceeds the height of the first div? So that it doesnt start from the beginning, but continues within the same "width"

Comment: It should clear the first div, but only if its height is greater? I don't think you can do that with CSS alone; that would require some JS.

Answer (score 0):

Just add width: 500px to the last div.

Comment: Is there not a more dynamic way to do this, then giving it a fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:950px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.first, .second {
    float:left;
}
.first{
    height:200px;
    width:450px;
    background:red;
}
.second{
    max-width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
}
```

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TbRuB/6/

**UPDATED**

for dynamic way

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/TbRuB/

Comment: Is there not a more dynamic way to do this, then giving it a fixed width?